# How does jsfiddle mark up code? Is there a library for this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, mootools, jsfiddle

If you've ever used www.jsfiddle.net, you might notice that it marks up code with proper colorings, and various other helpers like translating tabs to four spaces or shift-tab.  With Firebug I see that it's doing this with an iFrame.  Is there an open source library to do this?  I want to let people write Python on a web page, but make it pretty like jsfiddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/).

Comment: This is exactly what jsFiddle is using

Answer (score 2):

Look [here](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) (SyntaxHighlighter)

Here you can find a simple [tutorial](http://www.tellingmachine.com/post/Setting-up-SyntaxHighligther-for-BlogEngineNET-in-the-bare-bone-fashion.aspx).